# Impossible to make a migration with mysql and django

Tags: python, mysql, django, docker

I'm developing a web application with django on docker, on Windows 10.
I'm getting an error when trying to do the data model migrations, and I've tried everything I've seen in other threads of this same topic. I'm using mysql.
The error is shown below:
[image]

I've installed python3-dev, default-libmysqlclient-dev, mysqlclient, python3-mysqldb but it still shows the same error. I also tried to install the wheel file from this site: [enter link description here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient), but it indicates to me that it is not compatible, even having tried several files.

You can see how my dockerfile is made:

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /proyectoCDN
COPY requirements.txt .
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev
RUN apt-get install -y default-libmysqlclient-dev
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install python3-mysqldb
RUN pip install mysqlclient
# COPY mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64 .
# RUN pip install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 3306
```

the settings for my django project are shown below

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    #'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',

    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'mariadb',
    'USER': 'javier',
    'PASSWORD': 'javier',
    'HOST': 'db',   # Or an IP Address that your database is hosted on
    'PORT': '3306',

 }
}
```

Inside the container I see that I have installed the following components:
[image: packages installed]

I've been trying to solve the mistake for three days and I can't get any further.
I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: You are attempting to run makemigrations outside the container according to the screenshot.

Comment: That's right, I have to apply it inside the application container. Rookie mistake. I think it would be better to delete the thread.